# How to find index of a th element in a table by jquery?

Tags: jquery, indexing, html-table

I have an html table with some `TH` elements. I found a specific `TH` by jQuery and i need to know it's **index**.
I found `TH` by some code like this:

```
var th = $("#txtmin").parent();
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this way:

```
$("#txtmin").closest('th').index();
```

- [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/)
- [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#txtmin").parent().index();
```